# Como adicionar conteúdo no arraylist sem sobreescrever em java

Tags: java

Boa tarde.
Eu tenho um atributo array list e em cada espaço desse array list eu quero adicionar uma lista de 6 numeros inteiros, ao adicionar o primeiro tudo certo, porém ao adicionar os próximos eles começam a sobreescrever, podem me ajudar?

````
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        ArrayList<String[]> jogos = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[] bilhete = new String[6];

        int num = 0;
        char resposta = 's';
        int cont = 0;
        String aux = "";
        while (resposta == 's') {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++) {
                num = sc.nextInt();
                aux = String.valueOf(num);
                System.out.println(aux);
                bilhete[i] = aux;
            }
            ;
            jogos.add(bilhete);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(jogos.get(cont)));

            System.out.println("Mais um?");
            resposta = sc.next().charAt(0);
            cont++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(jogos.get(0)));

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(jogos.get(1)));

    }

}```
````

Answer (score -2):

O problema é que vc está reaproveitando o mesmo array de `String` todas as vezes.

Vc deveria criar um novo array de `String` para cada conjunto de números.

Para isto, mova a declaração da variável `bilhete` para dentro do `while`. Assim:

```java
while (resposta == 's') {
  String[] bilhete = new String[6];

  /* Aqui vai o restanto de seu código normalmente */
}
```

Comment: caraca, muito obrigado, eu estava há um tempão tentando resolver isso, não pensei que seria tão simples kkkk, valeu mesmo!